# Value correctly initializes, but breaks when updating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner learning C# and Unity and I'm following this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5U5TiW21Inw because I did some scripting beforehand and it had already been getting a bit messy I decided to start over and found this which doesn't declare valuables in a long page like I was doing prior, instead it creates a valuable tool. I'm finished with episode 2 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gj5LfqwGvgA) and everything but my recalculator seems to be working. When I play the scene the HP Formula makes the HP UI correctly displays 75 so I know it's sending and storing values correctly but when I press X which in Episode 1 we set up to increase testValueReference (Which later is switched to Strength) by 1, which it does. The problem is that as soon as I press X the HP value zeroes (nulls?).

The program so far consists of nine scripts in total and as the value initializes correctly I know it it's not in Formula.cs, HPFormula.cs, Value.cs, TextCharacterValue.cs, ValueFloat.cs, ValueInt.cs, or ValueStructure.cs. Mostly because these are short scripts that are easily copied when they appear in full and none of them use the recalculator function. The only two scripts that use the recalculator are Character.cs and ValueReference.cs.

Formula.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class Formula : ScriptableObject
{
    public abstract List<Value> GetReferences();
}


public abstract class FormulaInt : Formula
{
    public abstract int Calculate(StatsContainer stats);
}

public abstract class FormulaFloat: Formula
{
    public abstract float Calculate(StatsContainer stats);
}
```

HPFormula.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Formula/HP")]
public class HPFormula : FormulaInt
{
    // Health Formula below
    public Value vitality;
    int vit;
    public Value strength;
    int str;

    public override int Calculate(StatsContainer stats)
    {
        stats.Get(vitality, out vit);
        stats.Get(strength, out str);
        return vit * 6 + str * 2 + 30; // Placeholder Formula
    }
    public override List<Value> GetReferences()
    {
        List<Value> values = new List<Value>();
        values.Add(vitality);
        values.Add(strength);
        return values;
    }
}
```

TextCharacterValue.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TextCharacterValue : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Value trackValue;
    public Character character;

    void UpdateText()
        {
            string str = character.statsContainer.GetText(trackValue);
            GetComponent<Text>().text = str;
        }


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        character.statsContainer.Subscribe(UpdateText, trackValue);
        UpdateText();
    }
}
```

Value.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Value : ScriptableObject
{
    public string Name;
    public Formula formula;
}
```

ValueInt.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Value/Int")]
public class ValueInt : Value
{

}
```

ValueFloat.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Value/Float")]
public class ValueFloat : Value
{

}
```

ValueStructure.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Value/Structure")]
public class ValueStructure : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<Value> values;
}
```

ValueReference.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public abstract class ValueReference
{
    public Value valueBase;
    public Action onChange;
    public Action<Value> recalculate;

    public List<Value> dependent;

    public void RecalculateDependencies()
    {
        if (dependent != null)
        {
            foreach(Value v in dependent)
            {
                recalculate?.Invoke(v);
            }    
        }
    }
    public virtual string TEXT { get; internal set; }
    public abstract void Null();

    public class ValueFloatReference : ValueReference
    {
        public float value;
        public ValueFloatReference(Value _valueBase, float _value = 0)
        {
            valueBase = _valueBase;
            value = _value;
        }
        internal void Sum(float sum)
        {
            value += sum;
            onChange?.Invoke();
            base.RecalculateDependencies();
        }

        public override void Null()
        {
            value = 0f;
            onChange?.Invoke();
            base.RecalculateDependencies();
        }

        public override string TEXT
        {
            get
            {
                return valueBase.Name + " " + value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    public class ValueIntReference : ValueReference
    {
        public int value;

        public ValueIntReference(Value _valueBase, int _value = 0)
        {
            valueBase = _valueBase;
            value = _value;
        }
        internal void Sum(int sum)
        {
            value += sum;
            onChange?.Invoke();
            base.RecalculateDependencies();
        }

        public override void Null()
        {
            value = 0;
            onChange?.Invoke();
            base.RecalculateDependencies();
        }

        public override string TEXT
        {
            get
            {
                return valueBase.Name + " " + value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All seems fine on this end, so I assume the problem lies in Character.cs.

Character.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using static ValueReference;

public class StatsContainer
{
    public List<ValueReference> valueList;

    public StatsContainer()
    {
      valueList = new List<ValueReference>();
    }

    internal string GetText(Value value)
    {
        ValueReference valueReference = valueList.Find(x => x.valueBase == value);
        return valueReference.TEXT;
    }

    public void Sum(Value value, int sum)
    {
        ValueReference valueReference = valueList.Find(x => x.valueBase == value);
        if (valueReference != null)
        {
            ValueIntReference reference = (ValueIntReference)valueReference;
            reference.Sum(sum);
        }
        else
        {
             Add(value, sum);
        }
    }

    private void Add(Value value, float sum)
    {
        valueList.Add(new ValueFloatReference(value, sum));
    }
    private void Add(Value value, int sum)
    {
        valueList.Add(new ValueIntReference(value, sum));
    }

    public void Get(Value value, out int state)
    {
        ValueReference valueReference = valueList.Find(x => x.valueBase == value);
        ValueIntReference valueInt = (ValueIntReference)valueReference;
        if (valueInt == null)
        {
            state = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            state = valueInt.value;
        }
    }
    public void Get(Value value, out float state)
    {
        ValueReference valueReference = valueList.Find(x => x.valueBase == value);
        ValueFloatReference valueFloat = (ValueFloatReference)valueReference;
        if (valueFloat == null)
        {
            state = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            state = valueFloat.value;
        }
    }
    
    public ValueReference GetValueReference(Value value)
    {
        return valueList.Find(x => x.valueBase == value);
    }
    public void Subscribe(Action action, Value value)
    {
        ValueReference valueReference = valueList.Find(x => x.valueBase == value);
        valueReference.onChange += action;
    }

    public void Subscribe(Action<Value> action, Value dependency, Value subscribeTo)
    {
        ValueReference valueReference = valueList.Find(x => x.valueBase == subscribeTo);
        if (valueReference.recalculate == null)
        {
            valueReference.recalculate = action;
        }
        if (valueReference.dependent == null)
        {
           valueReference.dependent = new List<Value>();
        }
        valueReference.dependent.Add(dependency);
    }

    public void Sum(Value value, float sum)
    {
        ValueReference valueReference = valueList.Find(x => x.valueBase == value);
        if (valueReference != null)
        {
            ValueFloatReference reference = (ValueFloatReference)valueReference;
            reference.Sum(sum);
        }
        else
        {
            Add(value, sum);
        }
    }
}
public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ValueStructure statsStructure;
    public StatsContainer statsContainer;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Init();
    }
    void Init()
    {
        InitValues();
        InitFormulas();
    }
    private void InitValues()
    {
        statsContainer = new StatsContainer();
        for (int i = 0; i < statsStructure.values.Count; i++)
        {
            Value value = statsStructure.values[i];
            if (value is ValueFloat)
            {
                statsContainer.valueList.Add(new ValueFloatReference(value, 5f));
            }
            if (value is ValueInt)
            {
                statsContainer.valueList.Add(new ValueIntReference(value, 5)); // (value, x) x = Initialized Value
            }
        }
    }
    private void InitFormulas()
    {
        foreach (ValueReference valueReference in statsContainer.valueList)
            if (valueReference.valueBase.formula)
            {
                valueReference.Null();
                if (valueReference.valueBase.formula is FormulaInt)
                {
                    FormulaInt formula = (FormulaInt)valueReference.valueBase.formula;
                    statsContainer.Sum(valueReference.valueBase, formula.Calculate(statsContainer));
                }
                else
                {
                    FormulaFloat formula = (FormulaFloat)valueReference.valueBase.formula;
                    statsContainer.Sum(valueReference.valueBase, formula.Calculate(statsContainer));
                }
                List<Value> references = valueReference.valueBase.formula.GetReferences();
                for (int i = 0; i < references.Count; i++)
                {
                    statsContainer.Subscribe(ValueRecalculate, valueReference.valueBase, references[i]);
                }

            }
        }
        public void ValueRecalculate(Value value)
        {
            ValueReference valueReference = statsContainer.GetValueReference(value);
            valueReference.Null();
            // Adds all relevant stat sources.
        }

    public Value testReferenceValue;
    public Value baseSkillPoints;
    public Value baseStrength;
    public Value baseVitality;
    public Value baseHP;
    public Value baseDexterity;
    public Value baseIntelligence;
    public Value baseLuck;

    private void Update()
    {
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
            {
                statsContainer.Sum(testReferenceValue, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To be clear, the expected result is as follows. When I run the program my HP UI displays 75 and my attributes are all initialized to 5. Then upon pressing X my Strength UI goes up and that should also increase my HP UI because of the HP Formula.

Instead, When I run the program my HP UI displays 75 and my attributes are all initialized to 5. Then upon pressing X my Strength UI goes up, but my HP UI goes to 0.

This leads me to believe the problem lies specifically in the Recalculating.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the definition for `Value`?

Comment: When you step through with a debugger and/or set a breakpoint in the code that assigns values to the UI, (you've done that, correct?) When is the health UI set to 0? Where does that get called at, and why?

Comment: What is `Value`, `ValueStructure`, `ValueInt`, `ValueFloat`, `FormulaInt`, `FormulaFloat` ..... Please provide a [Minimal, **Reproducible** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Absolutely, they're all small and didn't have anything interesting about them so I did not include them in the original post as they didn't seem necessary. I am editing them in now.

Comment: @Ruzihm I've not done anything advanced to attempt to debug as I feared I would cause more harm and irreparable damage. In the video example Debug.log(str) is added to the HP Formula as well as Debug.log(vit) but adding them in and checking upm.txt doesn't really reveal anything useful. Creates the server instance, then the server, starts the server on a port, then "health request received" then nothing.

Comment: `Calculate`, the only place that contains the logic for calculating the health is only ever called once in your code, at the very start. Surely you need a way to have Character call your HP Formula's calculate after it nulls it in `ValueRecalculate`.

Comment: Indeed, after watching the tutorial, I see the teacher copy and paste a snippet from `InitFormulas` and put it at the end of `ValueRecalculate` a 20:43. It would be better to put that common code into a method and then call that method in both places.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I understand now. There's a quick jiggle at 20:43 and I didn't notice the paste and thought it was still centered on the copy. I didn't want to watch it on faster than normal speed so that was very easy to miss for me, great spot! Is it better to create a method for that? I assumed it was so that you can use the same code to both initialize and update the values independently. If I'm understanding you correctly I essentially do not need the Recalculator method, I just simply call the calculator once at the start of the game, and then again whenever I need to recalculate?

Comment: @TCGA Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes sorry, I have been messing about with some of the suggested updates but the initial problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor the Formula recalculation code into its own method then call that in `InitFormulas` and `ValueRecalculate`. I would also do some renaming for the sake of clarity and also use a switch statement instead of a long if/else if/else for type checking:

```
// for fast error detection
using UnityEngine.Assertions;

private void InitFormulas()
{
    foreach (ValueReference valueReference in statsContainer.valueList)
    {
        if (valueReference.valueBase.formula)
        {
            RecalculateFormulaReference(valueReference);

            List<Value> references = valueReference.valueBase.formula.GetReferences();
            for (int i = 0; i < references.Count; i++)
            {
                statsContainer.Subscribe(RecalculateFormulaByValue,
                        valueReference.valueBase, references[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void RecalculateFormulaReference(ValueReference valueReference)
{
    valueReference.Null();

    // better to use a switch with pattern matching like this
    switch (valueReference.valueBase.formula)
    {
        case FormulaInt formula:
            statsContainer.Sum(valueReference.valueBase, 
                    formula.Calculate(statsContainer));
            break;

        case FormulaFloat formula:
            statsContainer.Sum(valueReference.valueBase, 
                    formula.Calculate(statsContainer));
            break;

        default:
            Assert.IsTrue(false, "Unsupported Formula Type");
    }
}

// more descriptive name
public void RecalculateFormulaByValue(Value value)
{
    ValueReference valueReference = statsContainer.GetValueReference(value);
    RecalculateFormulaReference(valueReference);
}
```